# Monitoring memory (sharedm buffered, cached) for Xserve

Tags: monitoring, mac-osx-server, performance-monitoring, snmp, xserve

I am trying to monitor detailed memory useage over time for MacOSX /Xserver. NetSNMP version 5.4.2.1 on MacOS 10.6 does not report the following mibs

```
 oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.11"  alias="memTotalFree" type="integer"
 oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.13" alias="memShared"    type="integer" 
 oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14"  alias="memBuffer"    type="integer"
 oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15" alias="memCached"    type="integer"
```

This means that I cannot use NetSNMP to monitor memory effectively. If I can get these stats from some command line utility then they can be exposed to SNMP and I can collect them easily, but I don't see any low level MacOS specific command line tools for reading these statistics.

I would appreciate if you can recommend any tool or collector which would help me store memory statitics for MacOS/XServe for a longer period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article here, I think you'll find what you need in there.

http://www.bynkii.com/archives/2007/12/a_primer_to_snmp_on_mac_os_x_1.html

Comment: Oh, and are you sure your community string isn't restricted to certain OIDs?

Comment: thanks, I have basic snmp collection already setup. I can get total mem and available mem with snmp walk, but not the cache, buffered or shared)

Comment: maybe you can install a different version via MacPorts?